# how to display the input from another class(java)

Tags: java

I am working on my hw which is about creating a student record system and I don't know why my code could not display all of my input. Could you guys give me some suggestion on solving this problem?
My expected output is:  0: first name, lastname, id, student number, score

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;`
    public class semifinal{
        static String[][] records = new String[50][50];
        static int num = 0;
        public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Student record management system!");
            System.out.println();
            int i, n = 0;
            while(true){
                System.out.println("enter 'input' for inputting student's records"); 
                System.out.println("enter 'update' for updating the student's records"); 
                System.out.println("enter 'search' for searching the student's records"); 
                System.out.println("enter 'display' for displaying all students according to the final exam scores.");
            String word = kb.nextLine();
            if(word.equals("input")){
                System.out.println("Input student["+num+"]:");
                System.out.println("input <first name> ");
                String firstname = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <last name> ");
                String lastname = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <ID> ");
                String id = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <Student Number>");
                String num = kb.nextLine();
                insert(firstname, lastname, id, num);
            }else if(word.equals("update")){
                System.out.println("Enter the student number to update the student records"); 
                String num = kb.nextLine(); 
                System.out.println("Update the final exam score:"); 
                String score = kb.nextLine(); 
                update(num, score);
            }else if(word.equals("search")){
                System.out.println("Enter the student number to search the student records");
                String number = kb.nextLine();
                String[] input = search(number);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(input[0]+" "+input[1]+" "+input[2]+" "+input[3]+" "+input[4]+" ");           

            }else if(word.equals("display")){ 
                Display();

            }else{
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input again!");

            }
        }
    }
    public static void insert(String firstname, String lastname, String id, String num){
        for(int i = 0; i<records.length; i++){
        records[i][0] = firstname;
        records[i][1] = lastname;
        records[i][2] = id;
        records[i][3] = num;
        i++;
    }
    }
    public static void update(String num, String score){
        for(int i = 0; i<records.length; i++){
        records[i][4] = score;
        String[] update = search(num);
        update[4] = score;
        }
    }
    public static String[] search(String number){
        for(int i = 0; i<records.length; i++){
            if(number.equals(records[i][3])){
                 return records[i];
                 }
            }
            return null;
        }

   public static void Display(){
                sort();
                for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
                    System.out.println(num+" "+records[i][0]

+" "+records[i][1]+" "+records[i][2]+" "+records[i][3]+" "+records[i][4]);
            }
        }

        public static void sort(){
            int[] sort = new int[num];
            for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
                sort[i] = Integer.parseInt(records[i][4]);
            }
            for(int i = 0; i<num-1; i++){
                for(int j = i+1; j<num; j++){
                    if(sort[j]<sort[i]){
                        int temp = sort[j];
                        String[] x = records[j];
                        records[j] = records[i];
                        records[i] = x;
                        sort[j] = sort[i];
                        sort[i] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there anything wrong on my code? I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: What exactly you expect out of your code?

Comment: sorry that i forgot to mention.

Comment: My expected output is:  0: first name, lastname, id, student number, score and the score would be sorted

Comment: Please read [mcve]

Comment: There are many flaws with logic. Why `for loop` while inserting single record? Why you are using `num` variable for two purposes?

Comment: Why printing `records[i][4]` when nothing is stored in it?

Comment: I am just the beginner of java but i was required to complete a complex code by my lecturer... maybe this could explain why i created a messy code ;(

Answer (score 1):

You are shadowing your `num` variable

You have it set as a field

```
int num = 0;
```

but then within your code you also have

```
String num = kb.nextLine();
```

Probably this should be replaced with

```
num = Integer.valueof(kb.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many logical errors with the code. I have highlighted some of them in comments. I have fixed it partially rest you can work upon.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Student record management system!");
        System.out.println();
        int i, n = 0;
        while(true){
            System.out.println("enter 'input' for inputting student's records");
            System.out.println("enter 'update' for updating the student's records");
            System.out.println("enter 'search' for searching the student's records");
            System.out.println("enter 'display' for displaying all students according to the final exam scores.");
            String word = kb.nextLine();
            if(word.equals("input")){
                System.out.println("Input student["+ ++num +"]:");
                System.out.println("input <first name> ");
                String firstname = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <last name> ");
                String lastname = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <ID> ");
                String id = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("input <Student Number>");
                String studNum = kb.nextLine();
                insert(firstname, lastname, id, studNum);
            }else if(word.equals("update")){
                System.out.println("Enter the student number to update the student records");
                String num = kb.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Update the final exam score:");
                String score = kb.nextLine();
                update(num, score);
            }else if(word.equals("search")){
                System.out.println("Enter the student number to search the student records");
                String number = kb.nextLine();
                String[] input = search(number);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(input[0]+" "+input[1]+" "+input[2]+" "+input[3]+" "+input[4]+" ");

            }else if(word.equals("display")){
                Display();

            }else{
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid input again!");

            }
        }
    }
```

No need of loop in insert.

```
public static void insert(String firstname, String lastname, String id, String studNum){
        int index = num -1;
        records[index][0] = firstname;
        records[index][1] = lastname;
        records[index][2] = id;
        records[index][3] = studNum;
    }
```

No need to print index 4 in display (commented out sort as did not get time to fix that if any).

```
public static void Display(){
        //sort();
        for(int i = 0; i<num; i++){
            System.out.println(num+" "+records[i][0]

                    +" "+records[i][1]+" "+records[i][2]+" "+records[i][3]);
        }
    }
```

Now it will print records at least.

Comment: I inserted one record and then selected display to print. It is printing.

Comment: yes can be. I could not debug sort method but atleast it will get you going :)